# LibGDX Java JUnit Testing

Tags: java, android, junit, libgdx

I am making an android game with the libGDX Java game library. I would like to test my code but not quite sure how to go about it. I have set up testing and run sample tests like.

```
public class UnitTestExample {

    @Test
    public void oneEqualsOne() {
      assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

Now how do I test a function like

```
public void addListenerToExitButton(){

    buttonExit.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {Gdx.app.exit();
        }
    });

}
```

This function adds a LibGDX event to a button called buttonExit (In this case, the event is to exit the game.)

Answer (score 0):

I use [JMockIt](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html#mocked) for unit testing for my LibGdx projects and it works like a charm.

For your case, I assume the method you want to test is in a screen class, in other words, that is the class you are testing. Therefore you need to mock up all dependencies of this class and then instantiate it.Again I assume that button instance would be a private member of that class. So, under normal circumstances, you can not access it from your test code. JMockit can help you with that:

```
TextButton buttonToTest = (TextButton) Deencapsulation.getField(yourScreenUnderTest, "yourButtonName");
buttonToTest.toggle();
```

Above code will get the button and emulate **click** event on it. In this context, Gdx.app is a dependency and you already have mocked it up. What it means that, when your button is clicked, your mock instance will expect and **exit** call without any parameters. So, if you add this to your expectations, you are done.

Simple and elegant =]